# Play Framework - TemplateLoader with a different language

Tags: internationalization, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using play 1.2.4. My application is running in several languages. I need to send emails to clients by an admin user. However, admin users language setting is fixed and I need to send emails to client in their preferred language. I am rendering email temlates with `TemplateLoader` but I could not find a way to render my templates with another language option?

Is there a way to render templates with a different language option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Lang.set("language_code");` should give you what you need.

In normal templates, you can override the current browser defined language pack by using

```
 Lang.change("fr");
```

or

```
 Lang.set("fr");
```

You can read about it [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/i18n).

[Looking at the source code](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/i18n/Lang.java), `change` will modify the user's cookie, which is no good for your use case, but `set` changes the language pack for the current thread, so this should give you exactly what you need.

Comment: I was not aware of the difference between set and change.. many thanks for this great answer ;)